Как записать все данные в файл за раз внутри цикла pygame?
while True:
with open('file.txt', 'w+') as file:
    file.write(input('Please enter a string: '))
    file.seek(0)
    print(file.readline())
    file.flush()

Вот пример кода. Даже с использованием file.flush() данные записываются только при завершении программы. Как записывать их при окончании блока with open?

как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример

Вы каждый раз в цикле открываете файл заново и пишете в его начало. Рабочий вариант такой
with open('file.txt', 'w+') as file:
    while True:
        file.write(input('Please enter a string: '))
        file.flush()

Ну или так:
while True:
    with open('file.txt', 'a+') as file:
        file.write(input('Please enter a string: '))

